# Parallax Live Wallpaper Scrolling too Far

Tags: android, parallax, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I've designed a live wallpaper that uses parallax scrolling.  In order to scale the wallpaper to the size of the user's screen I use:

`int height = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;`

I then scale the image by dividing the `height` by the height of the image.  In this case, the image is 1000x563.  This ensures that the image fits to the users height dimension and that there is enough width for the parallax scrolling.

This works fine on most phones, but for some reason on some LG phones, the picture scrolls too far.  For example, on an LG G2, with a resolution of 1920x1080, with four home screens, by the third home screen (when swiping from the left), the right 10% or so of the image starts flashing, and the entire fourth home screen also shows the flashing distortion.

I can't figure out why this happens because the scaler I am using should give me plenty of width to scroll through.  `height` / 563 = 3.1545923.  When multiplying the scaler, 3.1545923 by the width of the image (1,000), I get 3,154.  If the screen width is 1080, I should only need double that for the parallax scrolling, which would be 2,160.

I've added Log statements to the `onOffsetsChanged` method and here's what I get for xOffset and xPixelsOffset:

Screen 1:
xPixelOffset: 0.0
xOffset: 0.0

Screen 2:
xPixelOffset: -360.0
xOffset: 0.3334

Screen 3: 
xPixelOffset: -720.0
xOffset: 0.6667

Screen 4:
xPixelOffset: -1080.0
xOffset: 1.0

I've tried this same code on my Note 3 and everything works fine.  That phone has the same exact resolution (although a bigger screen) as the LG G2 (except the height is slightly larger (1920 vs. 1776) because the G2 has a menu bar on the bottom that takes away from the usable home screen).

Any ideas?  It's almost as if the parallax scrolling on the LG phones scrolls farther than it should, but it shouldn't since the `xPixelOffset` value from above properly goes from 0 to 1080.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with this for a while, I still don't understand why this is happening, but I found a way around it.  Rather than using `xPixelOffset` in my `draw()` method, I use a custom variable, `mmPixel` that is calculated by:

```
mmPixel = (float) (((xOffset *.5) * screenWidth) * -1);
```

This basically is the same as using `xPixelOffset`, except it moves it only half as far on each swipe.  I still don't understand why I need to divide by two, since the offset is 1080 and my image is scaled to be much larger, but if anyone else runs into this problem, this should work.

This also resolves another issue that I didn't mention before, but some launchers (for some reason) fail to move the image as far as it should.  With Nova Launcher, for example, using `xPixelOffset` only moved the image a total of 360 pixels.  I have no idea why some launchers to do this, but ditching `xPixelOffset` and calculating it manually based on the screen's width and `xOffset` solves this problem too.